# Running LimaCharlie Adapter in Docker Container at Google Run gives file name to long

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a Docker container where I want to run a LimaCharlie Adapter that receives syslog.

However when I try to build the Docker container it does not take the **CMD [ "/bin/sh","..." ]** command because the file name is to long.

**Dockerfile**

```
# Specify Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils file

# Open port
EXPOSE 8080

# Download LimaCharlie Adapter (will download as file name "64" to /opt/64)
ADD https://downloads.limacharlie.io/adapter/linux/64 /opt
RUN cd /opt
RUN mv /opt/64 /opt/lc_adapter


# Create logcollector.service file for LimaCharlie
RUN chmod +x /opt/lc_adapter
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "./opt/lc_adapter syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=1-2-3-4-5 client_options.identity.oid=6-7-8-9-0 client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=MySensor client_options.sensor_seed_key=MySensor port=8080 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=true" ]
```

The **lc_adapter** file is a executable.

```
# file lc_adapter
lc_adapter: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=2MLFP8X_NxNWUzoPPZVD/MjzxEyHS5R7MY7guaGpe/avSLCqnqTExmYGH0Zsvo/pJ5s9HhisDNA_DZr4fJT, with debug_info, not stripped
```

**Error:**

```
PS C:\Users\admin\code\syslog-to-limacharlie-docker-main> docker run syslog-to-limacharlie-docker-main
/bin/sh: 0: cannot open ./opt/lc_adapter syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=1-2-3-4-5 client_options.identity.oid=6-7-8-9-0 client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=MySensor client_options.sensor_seed_key=MySensor port=8080 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=true: File name too long
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the `CMD` into separate words; remove the `/bin/sh` invocation at the beginning.

```bash
CMD ["/opt/lc_adapter", "syslog", "client_options.identity.installation_key=1-2-3-4-5", ...]
```

Unix internally handles commands as a list of "words", where the first word is the command to run.  When you use the JSON-syntax `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT`, or rarely `RUN`) you explicitly and directly provide that list of words.

That `CMD` string, formatted differently, tries to run `/bin/sh './opt/lc_adapter syslog ...'`.  That is, it looks in the `opt` subdirectory of the current directory, for a file named `lc_adapter syslog ...`, including the spaces as the part of the filename; and then it asks the system Bourne shell to run that as a script.  Breaking it up into words yourself helps the system understand which is the command and which is the options; and since `lc_adapter` is a standalone binary and not a shell script, you can't use `sh` as an interpreter to run it.

(Possibly you are missing an `sh -c` option, which asks the shell to read the next argument word and execute it as a command; but if you were going to do that, using the shell form of `CMD`, without the JSON-array syntax at all and without explicitly naming `/bin/sh` will be simpler.)